# only take photos to exclude 3d object in ar?

Tags: arkit, snapshot, realitykit

i want to take photo in arkit ,but don't want to include 3d object.

realitykit  snapshot(saveToHDR:completion:)
Takes a snapshot of the current view in iOS.

```
arView.snapshot(saveToHDR: false) { (image) in

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)}
```

[image: On the **right** is a picture of the phone,The **left** hand side is the desired result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ARSession`'s `currentFrame.capturedImage` for this purpose

```
if let pixelBuffer = session.currentFrame?.capturedImage {
  let image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer)
  // Save or process the image here
}
```